# WinRM fails: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have two servers (sourceserver1 and destinationserver1). They are not on the same network segment, but do have connectivity. Today, Invoke-Command stopped working when sourceserver1 tries to connect to destinationserver1 and I am not sure why. PowerShell shows the error:

> [<destinationserver1's IPv4>] Connecting to remote server
> <destinationserver1's IPv4> failed with the following error message :
> The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.
> Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
> requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
> service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
> destination is the WinRM service, run the  following command on the
> destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
> quickconfig". For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

On destinationserver1, I checked:

- Ran: winrm quickconfig
- Result: WinRM already configured
- Ran: Get-WSManInstance winrm/config/listener -Enumerate
- Result:

  cfg                   : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/listener

  xsi                   : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

  lang                  : en-US

  Address               : *

  Transport             : HTTP

  Port                  : 5985

  Hostname              :

  Enabled               : true

  URLPrefix             : wsman

  CertificateThumbprint :

  ListeningOn           : {127.0.0.1, <destinationserver1's IPv4>, ::1, <destinationserver1's IPv6>}
- Ran: winrm get winrm/config
- Result: No IPv4 or IPv6 filters
- Ran: netstat -aon | find "5985"
- Result:

  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57526    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57544    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57585    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    [::]:5985              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

On sourceserver1, I checked:

- Ran: (get-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts).value
- Result: found the IP of destinationserver1, which is how I am trying to connect
- Ran: telnet <destinationserver1's IPv4> 5985
- Result: the connection was successful
- Ran: Test-NetConnection <destinationserver1's IPv4> -port 5985
- Result:

  ComputerName           : <destinationserver1's IPv4>

  RemoteAddress          : <destinationserver1's IPv4>

  RemotePort             : 5985

  InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet

  SourceAddress          : <sourceserver1's IPv4>

  PingSucceeded          : True

  PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms

  TcpTestSucceeded       : True

Other connectivity, like "ping" works, in both directions.

Not sure what else to check.

Comment: probably better off asking on Super User. Other than that, are they on the same domain?

Comment: No, one is in a workgroup and the other is in a domain but this has been working for over a year.

Comment: are both connections set to private?

Comment: Yes, they are both "private".

Comment: and the WinRM service are running on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

I'am facing the similar issue

Connecting to remote server x.x.x.x failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

- CategoryInfo : OpenError: (172.28.6.32:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken

But it starts working after I manually RDP to the VM.

Please suggest what setting need to be applied on VM to avoid this error.